# SELECT same columns of Foreign table multiple time

Tags: sql

I have tables as follows:

ORG

```
    id  Name     media_budget  p_contact  s_contact  
------  -------  ------------  ---------  -----------
     1  FIFA          4654623          1            3
     2  FIFA_AP          1234          2            3
     3  ICC            203254          3            2
```

USERS

```
    id  fname    lname   contact  email            
------  -------  ------  -------  -----------------
     1  JHONE    MICHEL   124552  email@gmail.com  
     2  William  Martin   254623  gmail@email.com  
     3  Ann      Lee      321546  lee@gmail.com
```

I want to SELECT user.fname for ORG.p_contact and ORG.s_contact for each row in ORG, following statement works fine with single record in ORG however, when query return multiple rows it throws an error

```
"Error Code: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row"
```

my statement is:

```
SELECT o.Name, o.media_budget,
(SELECT u.fname AS primaryName    FROM org o LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON o.p_contact = u.id) AS PrimaryContact,
(SELECT usr.fname AS SecondaryName  FROM org og LEFT OUTER JOIN users usr ON og.s_contact = usr.id) AS SecondaryContact
 FROM org o;
```

What should be changed in sub-query to achieve desire result :

```
    id  Name    media_budget  PrimaryContact      SecondaryContact  
------  ------  ------------  --------------      ----------------
     3  ICC           203254          Ann            William
     4  FIFA            2656          JOHN            Ann
```

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  (2) How do you calculate `id` and `media_budget`?

Comment: Did you ever get this working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You just want to do some simple inner joins, like this:

```
SELECT o.Name, o.media_budget, p.fname AS PrimaryContact, s.fname AS SecondaryContact
  FROM org o
       INNER JOIN users p on o.p_contact = p.id
       INNER JOIN users s on o.s_contact = s.id
```

Comment: it only return the first row not all:

ICC           203254  Ann             William

Comment: This query should return all the rows as you specified. I'm not sure why you're not seeing that.